# Getting random object of a model with django-rest-framework

Tags: django, random, django-rest-framework

In my Django project I need to provide a view to get random object from a model using django-rest-framework. I had this ListAPIView:

```
class RandomObject(generics.ListAPIView):
   queryset = MyModel.objects.all().order_by('?')[:1]
   serializer_class = MyModelSerializer
   ...
```

It worked fine but `order_by('?')` takes a lot of time when launched on big database. So I decided to use usual Python random.

```
import random

def pick_random_object():
   return random.randrange(1, MyModel.objects.all().count() + 1)

class RandomObject(generics.ListAPIView):
   queryset = MyModel.objects.all().filter(id = pick_random_object())
   ...
```

I found out a strange thing when tried to use this. I launched Django development server and sent some GET requests, but I got absolutely the same object for all of the requests. When dev server restarted and another set of requests sent I'm getting another object, but still absolutely the same one for all of requests - even if `random.seed()` was used first of all. Meanwhile, when I tried to get a random object not via REST but via `python manage.py shell` I got random objects for every time I called `pick_random_object()`.

So everything looks good when using shell and the behavior is strange when using REST, and I have no clue of what's wrong.

Everything was executed on Django development server (`python manage.py runserver`).

Comment: Don't know a huge amount about python/django, but this issue implies that the same seed is being used for the random number generator. What argument are you passing to random.seed?

Comment: @Slicedpan I pass no argument actually. As I understand, time seed is used as default when nothing sent. For the shell everything works acceptable even without `seed()` so I don't think the glitch concentrated in it.

Comment: yeah thats what the docs say. your code above seems to assume that the ids for the objects are consecutive and are numbered from 1, are you sure that's always correct

Comment: @Slicedpan Well, yes. At least it is correct for all the cases I tested this stuff on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @CarltonGibson noticed, `queryset` is an attribute of `RandomObject` class. Hence it cached and cannot be changed any later. So if you want to make some changeable queryset (like getting random objects at every request) in some `APIView`, you must override a `get_queryset()` method. So instead of

```
class RandomObject(generics.ListAPIView):
   queryset = MyModel.objects.all().filter(id = pick_random_object())
   ...
```

you should write something like this:

```
class RandomObject(generics.ListAPIView):
   #queryset = MyModel.objects.all().filter(id = pick_random_object())
   def get_queryset(self):
      return MyModel.objects.all().filter(id = pick_random_object())
```

Here `pick_random_object()` is a method to get random `id` from the model.

Answer (score 2):

Since it's an attribute of the class, your queryset is getting [evaluated and cached](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#caching-and-querysets) when the class is loaded, i.e. when you start the dev server.

I'd try pulling a list of primary keys, [using `values_list()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) — the `flat=True` example does exactly what you need. [Ideally cache that](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/). Pick a primary key at random and then use that to `get()` the actual object when you need it.

So, how would that go?

I'd define a method on the view. If you forget the caching, the implementation might go like this:

```
# Lets use this...
from random import choice

def random_MyModel(self):
    """Method of RandomObject to pick random MyModel"""
    pks =  MyModel.objects.values_list('pk', flat=True).order_by('id')
    random_pk = choice(pks)
    return MyModel.objects.get(pk=random_pk)
```

You might then want to cache the first look up here. The caching docs linked above explain how to do that. If you do cache the result look into the [`db.models` signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/ref/signals/#module-django.db.models.signals) to know when to invalidate — I guess you'd `post_save`, checking the `created` flag, and `post_delete`.

I hope that helps.

Comment: I think you could not to edit the part concerning caching of querysets because I believe that is the problem in my case. And I didn't really get the idea about `values_list()`. Unfortunately, due to django-rest-framework API I should keep queryset in the same way as I described. I have to think of some other queryset or some way of sending a queryset or even some way to avoid caching in this particular case. And yes, that helped a lot, I didn't know about the caching.

Comment: Ok I re-added the bit on queryset caching and expanded my alternative suggestion. With luck that gives you enough to be going on with.