# Getting random object of a model with django-rest-framework after applying filters

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

So going based on this Stack Overflow question:

[Getting random object of a model with django-rest-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20522209/getting-random-object-of-a-model-with-django-rest-framework)

I am trying to figure out how to do this, but **after** applying the filter backend.

I have this class with these methods

```
class DictionaryRandomView(generics.ListAPIView):
    def get_queryset(self):
      return Dictionary.objects.all()

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

And several filter backends (can include if desired).

The problem is that I need to apply the filter backend **before** querying.

Should I do this inside the list method, or the get_queryset method?

For example, I have levels associated with a dictionary (for learning a language).

I want to limit my query to ONLY words with say, level 6, but then get random values (a dynamic number that I can pass as a filter) inside that set.

So pseudo-code for what I am trying to do would be something like this:

```
get_random_value("SELECT * FROM dictionary WHERE level = 6")
```

How can I do that in a DRF listAPIView?

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way would be to filter by level in the `get_queryset` method and then apply the other filters using the filter backends.

For the ordering part you can use `queryset.order_by('?')` if you need to randomly sort the results, but be careful with it as it can be ver resource intensive.

Additionally, I would also suggest to keep your response object consistent (i.e. always send a paginated response for this endpoint) so you don't have to deal with different objects in your frontend.